# Add image to menu item with ACF

Tags: custom-field, menus

I'm trying to add an image to menu item, can't get it to work.

Here is my code. 
`header.php`

```php
<?php wp_nav_menu(
                    array(
                        'theme_location'  => 'side-menu',
                        'container_class' => 'fixed-menu',
                        'fallback_cb'     => '',
                        'link_before'     => '<span>',
                        'lnk_after'       => '</span>',
                        'depth'           => 2,
                        'walker'          => new Understrap_WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker(),
                    )
                ); ?>
```

And here is the `function.php`

```php
// Header Side Menu
function etm_side_menu() {
  register_nav_menu('side-menu',__( 'Header Side Menu' ));
}
add_action( 'init', 'etm_side_menu' );


add_filter('wp_nav_menu_objects', 'wp_nav_menu_objects', 10, 2);

function wp_nav_menu_objects( $items, $args ) {

    // loop
    foreach( $items as &$item ) {

        // vars
        $icon = get_field('icon'); 


        // append icon
        if( $icon ) {

            $item->title .= '<img src='.$icon.'>';

        }

    }


    // return
    return $items;

}
```

The images that suppose to appear in the menu, just don't come on. Any help will be appreciated.

I am using understrap theme.

The desired markup is this

```html
<div class="fixed-menu">
        <ul>
            <li class="active">
               <a href="#">
                  <img src="img/fx-ic-1.png" alt="img">
                  <span>Главная</span>
               </a>
             </li>
             etc...
```

Comment: Unless your theme has added a hook, you need to use `add_filter('wp_nav_menu_objects'`... instead of `add_filter('my_wp_nav_menu_objects'`. `wp_nav_menu_objects` is the Core hook.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but to no avail, to icons are not populated.

Comment: You also need to update your `get_field()` call and pass in the post ID. Otherwise ACF can't get the data. It wouldn't hurt to simplify your code as you are testing to first add a `<span>` or something to every item, to verify you're using the right hooks, and then move on to the conditional part. Breaking it down into smaller steps helps identify which step is currently causing an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`get_field()` gets the field for the current post in [the loop](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/the-loop/), but the loop isn't used for menu items, so you need to specify which post you want to get the value from. In the case of menu items, each nav menu item is a `WP_Post` object, so you want to pass that:

```
foreach( $items as &$item ) {
    $icon = get_field( 'icon', $item );
    // etc.
}
```